# How to add a vertical line today on a linechart?

Tags: dc.js

I have a graph with the x axis being the date, and I'm trying to draw a line at today

```
var graph=dc.compositeChart(dom)
   .margins({top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 20, left:30})
    .height(150)
    .width(0)
    .dimension(dim)
    .x(d3.time.scale.utc().domain([dim.bottom(1)[0].dd,dim.top(1)[0].dd]))
    .round(d3.time.day.utc.round)
    .elasticY(true)
    .xUnits(d3.time.days.utc);
```

and it works fine, if I create manually a filter, it takes properly the right date range

However, when I try to add a line for today:

```
   function today (chart) {
        var x_vert = d3.time.day.utc(new Date());
        var extra_data = [
            {x: chart.x()(x_vert), y: 0},
            {x: chart.x()(x_vert), y: chart.effectiveHeight()}
        ];
        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
            .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
            .interpolate('linear');
        var chartBody = chart.select('g');
        var path = chartBody.selectAll('line#today').data([extra_data]);
        var path = path.enter()
                .append('path')
                .attr('class', 'today')
                .attr('stroke', 'red')
                .attr('id', 'today')
                .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                .style("stroke-dasharray", ("10,3"));
        path.attr('d', line);
    };

graph.on('pretransition', today);
```

It does draw the line... but at the wrong place (a further on the left).

Am I supposed to take into account the margins or something? I tried with different events (renderlet), same result.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: `chart.x()` should account for the margins okay. It's not just showing the line at midnight today, it's actually outside of today entirely?

Comment: the range of the graph is a it more than a month, and it's off by a few days. Now that you mention it, I wonder if the position is the same, no matter the date of today is, I'm checking further...

Comment: Happy to take a look if you create a fiddle or other live example.